# Cascading read parquet files outputted by spark

Tags: apache-spark, cascading

So I have a spark program outputted some parquet files, ex

```
part-r-00000-4b602595-62c5-4571-b3c6-0df335ffd2da.gz.parquet
```

then I use Cascading to read those parquet files (Those Cascading code will be converted to spark, but right now have to use Cascading here).

This Cascading program has no problem reading Parquet files outputted by a Cascading program.

However, when read parquet files outputted by spark, I get error

```
2016-11-09 10:31:30,183 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.gz]

2016-11-09 10:31:30,210 WARN cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputFormat: unable to get record reader, but not retrying

org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1
```

I am not sure what causes the problem.

Comment: The reason seems clear: `cascading.tap.hadoop.io.MultiInputFormat: unable to get record reader, but not retrying`. Looks like you need to add something to support `.gz.` compressed parquet files. Sorry, don't know cascading to give you a solution.

Comment: no sir, that's very helpful.  So xxx.gz.parquet  is actually compressed?   I mean, is that "gz" really means "this a compressed parquet" or that "gz" is just there in the filename?

Comment: cause I think a compressed parquet file should be named like   xxx.parquet.gz

Comment: this discussion seems relevant: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/1416/how-can-i-change-the-parquet-compression-algorithm.html  you can opt for no compression and maybe that will solve your issue

Comment: so I saw that, but wonder can I do something like spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=uncompressed?

Comment: I think the last entry is the key `df.write.option("compression","none").mode("overwrite").save("testoutput.parquet")`

Comment: Spark by default uses gz compression when you write parquet files, but you can change other compression format like snappy and other

Comment: @maasg  I changed the compression to uncompressed but I still get the same error, I can use spark to read the data though, so it's not corrupted...

Comment: You may have to ask Cascading people for that specific issue. They must have a mailing list of alike?